# Should the indefinite or zero article be used with the phrase "low cost"

Tags: grammar, articles, indefinite-article, zero-article

> You can build your first app on a small, single database at `low cost` in the serverless compute tier or a small compute size in the provisioned.

Should we use the indefinite article (`a low cost`) or the zero article (`low cost` omitting "a") in the sentence above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the "a article" or the "zero article" would be appropriate here, with meanings that differ only slightly, or subtly.

> at a low cost

This would mean that there are many possible low costs, and we are talking about one of those low costs.

> at low cost

This is referring to the general idea of "low cost", without stating that we are choosing any specific "low cost" value.

In practice, these two meanings are interchangeable, and native speakers would not make a distinction in meaning between them.